# How do I access an object's properties in an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called ChatRooms that has an array called messages in it. Inside messages, at each index is an object containing the properties name and message. How do i access the last object's name property in the javascript?

something like this:

```
 var messagerName = ChatRooms.find(messages.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var messages = [...] // this array assumes you have many objects inside it.
```

To access the last object:

```
var index = messages.length - 1;
```

The `.length` returns the length of an array (number of objects inside the array).  Remember, the first object is indexed at the value 0, so this is why we subtract 1.

```
var lastObject = messages[index];
```

Use dot notation to access the properties inside the object.

E.g

```
var name = lastObject.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean last message when you say last object, try this:

```
var messagerName = ChatRooms.find(messages[messages.length - 1].name);
```

Comment: messages is an array of objects

Comment: So u want to find the name property in the last object in messages array? [messages.length -1] will give u the index of the last object and '.name' will give you the name property.